# Beautifulsoup 4 spans containg '@' return strange results

Tags: python, css-selectors, scrapy

I was able to get the needed list of spans using the following :

```
attrs = soup.find_all("span")
```

This returns a list of spans as Key and Value :

```
[
    <span>back camera resolution</span>, 
    <span class="even">12 MP</span>
]

[
    <span>front camera resolution</span>, 
    <span class="even">16 MP</span>
]

[
    <span>video resolution</span>, 
    <span class="even"><a class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="b98b888f89c9f98a89dfc9ca" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection">[email protected]</a><script data-cfhash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script> - <a class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="4677767e7636067576203635" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection">[email protected]</a><script data-cfhash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script> - <a class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="5067626010616260362023" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection">[email protected]</a><script data-cfhash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script>
    </span>
]
```

The original HTML for this is :

[image]

Why the 'video resolution' is converted like this ?

Comment: Don't confuse the DOM viewer with the source the server gave the browser. BeautifulSoup can't execute the Javascript code the server sends.

Comment: It looks like the server uses a Javascript library to obfuscate *email addresses* automatically, the Javascript code is executed by the browser to re-insert the text.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wow !, If it is that complex, I think it is not that important I will skip it. thanks.

Comment: It's not that hard to reverse; I've posted a method in my answer; it takes the BeautifulSoup tree and replaces all occurrences with the de-obfuscated result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The site is using the [CloudFlare email protection feature](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-), which appears to have replaced *all strings* with `@` in them with obfuscated (XOR encryption) values to prevent scrapers from harvesting email addresses. Each replacement includes the JavaScript code to decode it.

BeautifulSoup won't execute the Javascript, but your browser *has* executed it and replaced the `<a class="__cf_email__">` tags with the resulting decrypted data.

You can do the same with a small Python 3 function; all the JavaScript code does is 'decrypt' the (hex-encoded) value by using the first byte as the key in a simple XOR decryption routine:

```
def decode(cfemail):
    enc = bytes.fromhex(cfemail)
    return bytes([c ^ enc[0] for c in enc[1:]]).decode('utf8')

def deobfuscate_cf_email(soup):
    for encrypted_email in soup.select('a.__cf_email__'):
        decrypted = decode(encrypted_email['data-cfemail'])
        # remove the <script> tag from the tree
        script_tag = encrypted_email.find_next_sibling('script')
        script_tag.decompose()
        # replace the <a class="__cf_email__"> tag with the decoded result
        encrypted_email.replace_with(decrypted)
```

To make the above work in Python 2, replace `bytes` with `bytearray`.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
...     <span>video resolution</span>,
...     <span class="even"><a class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="b98b888f89c9f98a89dfc9ca" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection">[email protected]</a><script data-cfhash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script> - <a class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="4677767e7636067576203635" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection">[email protected]</a><script data-cfhash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script> - <a class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="5067626010616260362023" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection">[email protected]</a><script data-cfhash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script>
...     </span>
... ''')
>>> deobfuscate_cf_email(soup)
>>> soup
<html><body><span>video resolution</span>,
    <span class="even">2160p@30fps - 1080p@30fps - 720@120fps
</span>
</body></html>
```